# Change mail attribute of Active Directory

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, runtime-error, change-password

I'm trying to change the mail and password attributes of Active Directory using java. To do this, it was generated a security certificate and imported into the certificate store of the jvm (carcerts). The connection is made using ssl successfully however when trying to change any field, eg mail,I get the following error message:

javax.naming.OperationNotSupportedException: [LDAP: error code 53 - 00002035: LdapErr: DSID-0C090B3E, comment: Operation not allowed through GC port, data 0, v1db1

source code:

```
// change mail
private void salvarEmailESenhaNoAd() throws IOException, NamingException {
    Properties mudaSenhaProperties = new PropertiesFactory().propertiesByJndi("mudaSenha");

    ADUtil adUtil = null;

    try
    {
        adUtil = new ADUtil(mudaSenhaProperties);

        adUtil.changeEmail("CN=018061671627,OU=SDS,OU=CS,OU=STI,OU=DG,OU=PRES,OU=TRERN,DC=tre-rn,DC=jus,DC=br", dadosUsuario.getEmail());

    }
    finally
    {
        if (adUtil != null)
        {
            adUtil.close();
        }
    }
}



public class ADUtil {

private LdapContext ldapContext = null;

public ADUtil(Properties properties) throws NamingException
{
    ldapContext = createUserContext(properties);
}


private LdapContext createUserContext(Properties properties) throws NamingException {


    String javaNamingFactoryInitial = properties.getProperty("java.naming.factory.initial");
    String javaNamingProviderUrl = properties.getProperty("java.naming.provider.url");
    String javaNamingSecurityAuthentication = properties.getProperty("java.naming.security.authentication");
    String javaNamingSecurityPrincipal = properties.getProperty("java.naming.security.principal");
    String javaNamingSecurityCredentials = properties.getProperty("java.naming.security.credentials");
    String javaNamingSecurityProtocol = properties.getProperty("java.naming.security.protocol");
    String javaNamingReferral = properties.getProperty("java.naming.referral");
    String javaNetSslTrustStore = properties.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore");
    String javaNetSslTrustStorePassword = properties.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword");

    Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();

    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", javaNetSslTrustStore);
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", javaNetSslTrustStorePassword);

    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, javaNamingFactoryInitial);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, javaNamingSecurityAuthentication);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, javaNamingSecurityPrincipal);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, javaNamingSecurityCredentials);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL, javaNamingSecurityProtocol); // para poder modificar password y grupos del usuario.
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, javaNamingProviderUrl);
    env.put(Context.REFERRAL, javaNamingReferral);

    return new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
}


public void changePassword(String userCN, String newPassword) throws NamingException, UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException {

    modifyAdAttribute(userCN, "unicodePwd", converteString(newPassword));
    System.out.println("Password changed for " + userCN);
}

public void changeEmail(String userDN, String newEmail) throws NamingException, UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException {

    modifyAdAttribute(userDN, "mail", converteString(newEmail));
    System.out.println("Email changed for " + newEmail);

} 


private void modifyAdAttribute(String userCN, String attribute, Object value) throws NamingException{
    ModificationItem[] modificationItem = new ModificationItem[1];
    modificationItem[0] = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE,
            new BasicAttribute(attribute, value));
    ldapContext.modifyAttributes(userCN, modificationItem);

}


private static byte[] converteString(String password) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
    String newQuotedPassword = "\"" + password + "\"";
    return newQuotedPassword.getBytes("UTF-16LE");
}

public void close() throws NamingException
{
    if (ldapContext != null)
    {
        ldapContext.close();
    }
}
```

---

Reading the attributes is usually done with the code below:

```
public class TesteLdap {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
private static SearchControls getSimpleSearchControls() {
    SearchControls searchControls = new SearchControls();
    searchControls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
    searchControls.setTimeLimit(30000);
    //String[] attrIDs = {"objectGUID"};
    //searchControls.setReturningAttributes(attrIDs);
    return searchControls;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException {


    try {

        Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://rndc10.tre-rn.jus.br:3269");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "user");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password");

        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL, "ssl");
        env.put(Context.REFERRAL, "ignore");

        String filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(CN=018061671627))";

        LdapContext ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
        ctx.setRequestControls(null);
        NamingEnumeration<?> namingEnum = ctx.search("OU=DG,OU=PRES,OU=TRERN,DC=tre-rn,DC=jus,DC=br", filter, getSimpleSearchControls());

        while (namingEnum.hasMore()) {
            SearchResult result = (SearchResult) namingEnum.next();
            Attributes attrs = result.getAttributes();
            System.out.println(attrs.get("cn"));
            System.out.println(attrs.get("displayname"));
            System.out.println(attrs.get("mail"));
            System.out.println(attrs.get("distinguishedName"));

        }
        namingEnum.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
```

---

My environment: Active Directory on Windows 2008R2 Standart, Open JDK 7 running on unbutu 12.10.

I would be grateful if someone help me because I've tried everything but I can not make it work.

Answer (score 1):

The error seems to be self-explanatory. You should perform this operation over LDAPS using port 636. 
Have you tried to use

```
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldaps://rndc10.tre-rn.jus.br:636");
```

(Note that ldaps:// is not mandatory if you specify ssl separately).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have RODCs (Read only DCs) in your environment? And if so, is rndc10.tre-rn.jus.br a RODC?

Perhaps you should be pointing to a DC that is writeable?

Have you tried updating this string:

```
 env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://rndc10.tre-rn.jus.br:3269");
```

to:

```
 env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldaps://rndc10.tre-rn.jus.br:3269");
                                    ^
```